# Gitolite on Dreamhost

Tags: perl, git, dreamhost, gitolite

I'm trying to install Gitolite as in the http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Gitolite

I get the error like :

`"make_path" is not exported by the File::Path module

Can't continue after import errors at gitolite/src/gl-system-install line 5

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at gitolite/src/gl-system-install line 5.`

There is a problem with perl but I could not find solution yet.

**server capabilities**
/usr/local/bin/perl
perl v5.10.0

Comment: My dreamhost server (twins.dreamhost.com) has 5.10.1, which has File::Path 2.07_03. Maybe they can switch your server if they can't upgrade your File::Path. Otherwise, you could use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to install your own version of Perl. Note that one of the Cwd tests fails on dreamhost, but it's harmless to ignore the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[At press time](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/ee81c52e805961a32665f77ed269d0f2fd211213/src/gl-system-install), `gl-system-install` calls [`make_path`](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.08/Path.pm#make_path) in one place, in the sub that begins at [line 75](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/ee81c52e805961a32665f77ed269d0f2fd211213/src/gl-system-install#L75):

```
sub check_dirs {
    for my $dir ( $bin_dir, $conf_dir, $hooks_dir ) {
        die "$dir should be an absolute path\n" unless $dir =~ m(^/);
        make_path($dir);
        -d $dir or die "$dir does not exist and could not be created\n";
    }
}
```

This particular usage is call-compatible with [`mkpath`](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.08/Path.pm#mkpath) instead. You don’t have to install a new File::Path module. Change line 5 of `gl-system-install` to

```
use File::Path qw(mkpath);
```

and line 78 to

```
mkpath($dir);
```

I encountered the same situation within the last week. After making the changes above, you can follow [gitolite’s installation instructions](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html) with no further snags.

---

**Update:** This issue is now [fixed in the gitolite repository](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/06eb52316452c74ca7698d26a834a8c71a496987).

Comment: amazing! worked like a charm :) you saved me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

`make_path` was introduced in File::Path 2.06_05.  You must be using an older version (Perl 5.10.0 came with File::Path 2.04).  Upgrade File::Path (or upgrade Perl, since [5.10 is no longer supported](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpolicy.html)).

Answer (score 2):

make_path is only available in File::Path 2.07. I'm not sure if it's your problem or not, but you might try updating File::Path:

`cpan File::Path`

or

`cpanp i File::Path`